# Output vector array into tex file, error

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to output the values of a vector array into a text 
but im getting this weird error

> no opeartor "<<" matches the operands, operand types are : std::ofstream << Person

Here is my code

```
class Person {
public:
    Person(string, string, int);
    string get_name() {
        return name;
    }
    string get_family() {
        return family;
    }
    int get_age() {
        return age;
    }



private:
    string name;
    string family;
    int age;


};

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("test.txt");

    vector <Person> persons;


    string N, F;
    int A;
    while (cin >> N >> F >> A) {

        Person tmpPerson(N, F, A);

        persons.push_back(tmpPerson);

        for (int i = 0; i < persons.size(); i++){
            myfile << persons[i] << " " << endl;
        }
        myfile.close();

    };
```

I have incuded the  and tried everything, but this error, persist, would be very thankful for some help !

Comment: Not related to the stated problem however you need to get your for loop and `myfile.close()`. out of your while loop.

Comment: Did you provide a `operator <<` overload that takes a `std::ostream` reference on the left side and a `Person` on the right? If not, there's your problem. If yes, you didn't do it correctly. If the latter, we can't possibly help because you didn't include it in your posted code.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. For instance: Does the class `Person` contain overloaded `operator<<`?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius The class can't contain that overload. It needs to be a free function (possibly friended to the mystery `Person` class). If the OP tried to implement it as a member function it wouldn't work (and maybe that's the problem, but without code, we'll never know, as you've pointed out).

Comment: @WhozCraig OK, I agree that it was poor choice of words. What I meant was: "Is `operator<<` overloaded for class `Person`?"

Comment: @WhozCraig Added the Person class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a function helper like this for your custom class Person.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Person& p)  
{  
    os << p._N << ' '  << p._F << ' ' << p._A << std::end; 

    return os;  
}
```